# How to make an autologin system in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, maui

I want users to be able to automatically login into my .NET MAUI app.

I have the login system done, but I don't know how to make the login persistent once they close the app.

This is my login system so far.

```
 public partial class Login
    {
        // User credentials
        string username;
        string password;

        // Try verification
        public async Task LoginVerification()
        {
            // Check if credentials are valid in the database.
            bool isValid = await CheckIfValid(username, password);

            if (isValid)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("User Was Found");
                // Do stuff after succesful login.
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("User Not Found");
                // Do stuff after unsuccesful login.
            }
        }

    }
```

How can I make it so they don't have to enter their credentials the next time they launch the application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is typically achieved by saving the user's login data and then performing an automatic login when necessary. This also ensures the credentials are still valid.

I recommend saving such data to .NET MAUI `Preferences` system.

This works with Key-Value pairs that are saved to the app's data.

This is an example of saving the user's password to the user's preferences.

```
// Create the password string
string myPass = "somePass";

// Save the password to the Preferences system
Preferences.Set("UserPassword", myPass); // The first parameter is the key
```

After saving the user's data to the app's preferences, you can retrieve it on app startup and perform an automatic login by using the `Get()` method.

```
// Get the password from the Preferences system
string passwordFromPrefs = Preferences.Get("UserPassword", "defaultPass");
```

Note that the `Get()` method requires you to pass a second argument for the default value. In case there is no data for the specified key in the app's preferences, the method will return this default value.